# Apex - Subtract minutes from DateTime Object

Tags: datetime, salesforce, subtraction, apex

I'd like to subtract 5 minutes from DateTime.now() May I know how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[`addMinutes()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Datetime_instance_methods.htm)**

It has **`add`** in it's name but nobody says you can't *pass a negative number*.

```java
DateTime dt = System.now();
DateTime earlier = dt.addMinutes(-5);
DateTime fullHour = dt.addMinutes( -dt.minute() ).addSeconds( -dt.second() );

System.debug(dt + '\t' + earlier + '\t' + fullHour);
```

---

```
2014-01-11 08:40:13     2014-01-11 08:35:13     2014-01-11 08:00:00
```

Answer (score -1):

Just subtract time in days (Double format) from `DateTime.now()` as follows:

i.e. 5 (minutes) = 5 / 1440 (days)

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.now() - Double.valueOf(5) / 1440;
```